# How can I use R to loop over levels of two factors

Tags: r, for-loop, conditional-statements

I am trying to code a factor variable to track between-year changes in another factor variable in R.

Suppose I have to following data strucutre:

```
df<-data.frame(id<-rep(seq(from=1,to=5,by=1),5), 
          year<-c(rep(2002,5), rep(2004,5), rep(2006,5), rep(2008, 5), 
                  rep(2010, 5)), factor<-rbinom(n=25,size=1,prob=0.5))

colnames(df)<-c("id", "year", "factor1")

df[,1]<-as.factor(as.character(df[,1]))

df[,2]<-as.factor(as.character(df[,2]))

df[,3]<-as.factor(as.character(df[,3]))

factor2<-c()
```

The Loop structure is as follows:

```
for(i in levels(df[,1])){
  for(j in levels(df[,2])){
    if(df[,3]>0){factor2<-1}
    else(factor2<-0)
  }
}
```

Which returns:

> factor2 as a numeric vector with 0 elements

My question is, how can I get this loop structure to work?

Comment: Can you explain a bit about where in that code you believe that you've created a factor (or a data frame, even)?

Comment: > class(df[,1])
[1] "numeric"
> df[,1]<-as.factor(as.character(df[,1]))
> class(df[,1])
[1] "numeric"

Comment: You have no factors in your code. If you did, when cbinding the data, you would lose them.

Comment: Ah, so you did not, in fact, include all the relevant code in your question. Please edit your question to remedy this.

Comment: Edit complete. The question stands

Comment: As Roman mentioned, `cbind` is a very bad way to create data frames. There's a function for creating data frames and it is called.....`data.frame()`! Using `cbind` will often result in a matrix, which only holds a single data type, so the factors are all being coerced.

Comment: Alright, so use data.frame in the future.

Comment: Are you looking for something like: `factor2 <- with(df,ifelse(as.numeric(as.character(factor1))>0,1,0))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your existing code replaces the contents of `factor2` in each iteration of the loop. To add a new value without specifying an index, you can use the `append()` function. However, even with `append()`, your code as written will simply make `factor2` a duplicate of `df[, 3]`.

What I believe you want to do is create a new factor that is set to 1 if ID in year X is different from ID in the previous year. Try the following code, replacing your `factor2<-c()` line and continuing from there:

```
factor2 <- vector()

for ( i in levels(df[, 1]) ) {

  dummy <- df[df$id==i, ]
  factor2 <- append(factor2, 0) 

  for ( j in 2:length(dummy[, 2]) ) {   

    if ( dummy[j, 3] != dummy[j-1, 3] ) {
      factor2 <- append(factor2, 1) 
    }

    else { 
      factor2 <- append(factor2, 0) 
    }

  }

}
```

This code appends a 0 to `factor2`, since ID will never be different in the first year as there is no previous year for comparison. Then for each subsequent year, it checks to see if the new value of `factor1` differs from the previous year's value. If so, it appends a 1 to `factor2`, otherwise it appends a 0.

At the end, for this example, `factor2` will be a length 25 vector. However, since it was populated in ID order, you can't just add it to `df`, you instead need to sort `df` on ID first, then add `factor2` to the results as a new column. Hope this helps!

Comment: is there a way to make this response more generalizable?

Example: If each unique id did not appear in each year (individual 1 entered the data in 2006)

Comment: The simplest way would be to add exception handling in the inner loop such that an NA is appended to factor2 if ID is NA. That would just be another if statement.